# How to set all element values in a non-primitive type array as a value/not null?

Tags: java, arrays, primitive-types

From my knowledge when you create a pointer (non-primitive type) it is null until it is assigned. With primitive types it has a default value of zero.
So for instance say I have the following code:

```
int value[numberOfDesiredElements]; //all values are zero, not null
value[] == null ? return true : return false; //returns false, is not null
```

Now say I do this with a non-primitive type like BigInteger:

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger[numberOfDesiredElements]; //All values are null, not default value.
value[anyElement] == null ? return true : return false; //Returns true, is null.
```

So my question is, is there a way to create a BigInteger array (or any non-primitive type array) with all values equal to zero, or to "" in a Strings case?

Comment: The code you are presenting is not valid Java. You cannot declare an `int` array that way, you can't compare an `int` to `null`, you can't assign an array to a `BigInteger`. And you cannot use `return` in a ternary operator expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do it with Array's fill method like:

```
String[] str = new String[10];
Arrays.fill(str, "");//set empty value as default to each element in array
```

It would just internally loop over the array and default each value to empty string.

Comment: Worth clarifying that that just works by looping the array. Source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#2412

Comment: Array.fill is just a loop I guess

Comment: @crl yes it is. `for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)
            a[i] = val;`

Comment: Is this a smaller way of writing the loop syntax then

Comment: @SMA how can I do this with the type BigInteger? Is there a way?

Comment: Try `Arrays.fill(<my big integer array>, BigInteger.ZERO);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Commons Lang library to do that, with ArrayUtils:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Integer[])

If you use maven, add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can handle the defaults for null values.

`public static int[] toPrimitive(Integer[] array)`

`public static int[] toPrimitive(Integer[] array, int valueForNull)`

`public static long[] toPrimitive(Long[] array)`

`public static long[] toPrimitive(Long[] array, long valueForNull)`

Example:

```
Integer[] integers = {new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3)};

int[] ints = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(integers,0);
```

Comment: This would be a great solution, but alas. Google has banned me from using outside libraries. Still thumbs up though